# Write CSV file to MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring, csv, multipart, netflix-feign

I am using Apache common CSV

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Code to write a CSV into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT;
final CSVPrinter csvPrinter;
try {
  csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(new PrintWriter(out), format);
  csvPrinter.printRecord("12,ABC,XYZ");
  csvPrinter.printRecord("13,LMN,PQR");
  csvPrinter.flush();
  csvPrinter.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I have a feign call to save file as:

```
ResponseEntity<ObjectResponseBo> uploadFile(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String var1, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile var2);
```

How can I convert the `ByteArrayOutputStream` to a `MultipartFile` object, so that I am able to use the csv file in my Feign call?

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381928/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-multipartfile)