# How to load a local file using MultipartFile in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, multipartform-data, multipartfile

How to consume an API which accepts only MultipartFile in spring boot?
Have to pass a file from Local Server (from some specific path)

```
@FeignClient(name = "abc-file-upload",url ="https://abc.xyz.app")
public interface ABCFeignClient {

    String AUTH_TOKEN = "Authorization";
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/v1/upload",consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    UploadFileResponse uploadFile(@RequestBody MultipartFile multipartFile, @RequestHeader(AUTH_TOKEN) String api_key);
}
```

Now I have to call this client method and have to pass a local file from a specific location like `(/Users/pradeepkumar/Desktop/File_Download/file1.jpg)`

How to get MultipartFile Object for a local file?

Comment: Maybe that could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381928/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-multipartfile
I guess you need to implement MultipartFile interface. In this implementation you will provide the file name and the data stream for it.

Comment: Thanks  Alexey Usharovski for your reply, as the solution you have suggested not worked for me, but I found the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378920/how-can-i-make-a-multipart-form-data-post-request-using-java and It's worked..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, MultiPartFile is an interface and we can create an object of its multiple implementations like below,

```
File file = new File("/Users/pradeepkumar/Desktop/File_Download/file1.jpg");
```

Once you have File object of your local file,

```
final MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(filename, filename, mimeType, FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));
```

Also, you can create your own implementation of this interface. Just override all methods and return expected data from all overridden methods.